# jQuery/CSS: trying to change margin-top of a sibling <div> in an click event

Tags: jquery, css

I have an HTML structure as follows

```
<div class="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    <p class="invisible">
         Lorem ipsum aequitatem etc.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
      Child 2
  </div>
  <div id="child3">
      Child 3
  </div>
</div>
```

I  currently have an event listener in jQuery which is listening for a click event on the first child. I then toggle the visibility of the `<p>` element by `toggleClass('.invisible')` which removes the `display:none` applied.

I am trying to simultaneously change the default behavior of the `<p>` content kicking the sibling divs to the bottom of the parent div container by changing the `margin-top` of the other two siblings. However, when I apply a class that has a negative `margin-top`, it does not actually change the siblings top margin.

Here are both of my current approaches and their shortcomings:

```
$('#child1').on('click', function(){
   $('#child1 p').toggleClass('invisible');

   //does not change margin-top as presumably it does not change
   //the margin-top value associated with the id
   $('#child2').toggleClass('new_margin_top');

   //changes magin-top but is awkward for obvious reasons after n >=2 iterations of the click event
   $('#child2').css('margin-top',' <arbitrary-number> px');
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebbnormal/qmnsc1ga/1/) that has the same behavior, so you can see what is happening:

Comment: `$(this).parent().find('sibling selector').css(...);`

Comment: You shouldn't be using a `.` in your `toggleClass` selectors. `toggleClass('.invisible')` should be `toggleClass('invisible')`

Comment: @r3wt Great idea. the problem is, how can I simulate that behavior only every n mod 2 == 1 times?

Comment: @Thalatta `if(n % 2 == 0) { //do shit }`